# Product price not being set for programmatically created quote item

Tags: magento-1.9, quoteitem, sales-quote, custom-quote

I am using the following code to set the product to the quote object

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$quote->addProduct($product,new Varien_Object(array('qty'   => $productid)));
```

The product and it's quantity is stored in the `sales_flat_quote_item` table on saving the quote but the price and base price is 0. The price is not set with the price of the product.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function `collectTotals()` before saving your instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`.

Proper code block would look like this:

```
$productId = 1;
$productQty = 15;

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty'   => $productQty)));

$quote->collectTotals(); // This is the line you're missing
$quote->save();
```

Comment: Yes I used it like this `$quote->collectTotals()->save();` but it didin't work